# Check if a node exist where field_a = Sessionvalue && field_b=arg1

Tags: nodes

Hello I need a an if else statment to check if a node with 2 given field values exist.(1 value from a Session and 1 from an Url argument)

I dont need to load the node I only want to check if it exist.

thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708).

Comment: I post an answer here for those who are looking for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get value from entity without loading the entity object. You can use [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)

**Example:**

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_id', 1)  
      ->fieldCondition('field_custom_field', 'value', '', '!=')
      ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  // field value exists!.
}
```